# Android - Dynamically change Item of Custom List View like slideshow effect

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, slideshow, custom-lists

I have one custom list view in which four items used, an imageview and three textviews. and I have five image uri for every imageview of the list and I want to change image dynamically within some duration for particular imageview item. I applied thread for changing image dynamically but its working on only one item of list view at a time . I want to change every imageview item of listview dynamically. What i do. Am i go in a right direction or i should try anything else.Please anyone suggest me.The help will be Highly appreciated..Thanks in Advance :)

here is my getView code-

```
final AQuery recycle = aq.recycle(view);

final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

// Create runnable for posting
final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
public void run() {

           animate_slide(recycle , currentimageindex);
           currentimageindex++;

        if(currentimageindex > 4){
            currentimageindex = 0;
                    }
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

                   mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

                  }

            }, delay, period);
```

and the method i call for animation-

```
private void animate_slide(AQuery recycle ,int ci) {

                            if(ci == 0){
                                Log.d("00000000000000","----------"+ci);
                                recycle.id(R.id.avatar).progress(R.id.progress).image(ApplicationConstants.IMG_URL_SUFFIX+picture.get(currentimageindex), true, true, 100, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);
                            }else if(ci == 1){
                                Log.d("11111111111111","----------"+ci);
                                recycle.id(R.id.avatar).progress(R.id.progress).image(ApplicationConstants.IMG_URL_SUFFIX+picture1.get(currentimageindex), true, true, 100, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);
                            }else if(ci == 2){
                                Log.d("2222222222222222","----------"+ci);
                                recycle.id(R.id.avatar).progress(R.id.progress).image(ApplicationConstants.IMG_URL_SUFFIX+picture2.get(currentimageindex), true, true, 100, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);
                            }else if(ci == 3){
                                Log.d("3333333333333333","----------"+ci);
                                recycle.id(R.id.avatar).progress(R.id.progress).image(ApplicationConstants.IMG_URL_SUFFIX+picture3.get(currentimageindex), true, true, 100, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);
                            }else if(ci == 4){
                                Log.d("00000000000000","----------"+ci);
                                recycle.id(R.id.avatar).progress(R.id.progress).image(ApplicationConstants.IMG_URL_SUFFIX+picture4.get(currentimageindex), true, true, 100, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);

                            }

                        }
```

Comment: I am using same process with static value than this is working fine .. but why is not work with dynamic value ?

Comment: Do you invoke your _getView code_ for every newly inflated view? Could you provide complete getView code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Gallary in your getView xml file
and you can have some work around there

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make it that complex. I think only the first item int the list animates, am I right?

I suggest not to use a new runnable, and change your `getView()` like this (I assume `currentimageindex` in your code is the position of the item in the `ListView`) :

```
// The view holder for better ListView
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1, text2, text3;
    ImageView image;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        /* Initialize views and add them to  the ViewHolder
         * 
         * ....
         * 
        */
        // Setting the position as a tag, so we can get it in the runnable
        holder.image.setTag(position);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                animate_slide(aq.recycle(holder.image), (int) holder.image.getTag());
            }

        }, when, period);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    /* do what you want with the texts...
     * 
     * ....
     * 
    */  

    return view;

}
```

**EDIT**: I figured out an easier solution. :)
We don't need any other thread.
Inside `getView()` put this code and it will automatically trigger the animation :

```
    // At first we load the animation 
    Animation slideAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context , R.anim.fade_in);
    slideAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);

    slideAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {/* Nothing*/}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            yourImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.newResource);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // Setting a delay after each animation.
            // This is the time between two animations.
            animation.setStartOffset(period);
        }

    });

    yourImageView.startAnimation(slideAnimation);
```

Finally, don't forget to cancel then animation, because it we said `slideAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);`. I suggest doing adding this method in your adapter class:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    slideAnimation.cancel();
}
```

And this in your activity :

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        yourListAdapter.onDestroy();
    }
```

**Hope it helps :)**